# wrapfigure environment vspace above figure

Tags: spacing, floats, wrapfigure

I am trying to use `wrapfigure` to place a `figure` within my document and I have noticed something odd occurring.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}
\begin{document}    
\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

The first figure wraps correctly and as expected, however the second figure seems to have dropped down by a line. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Here, the problem disappears if there is text before the first figure.

Comment: @Denis If there is text before the first figure then both are dropped down by 1 line, is there anyway to fix this without manually modifying the `\vspace`?

Comment: You are completely right. I was only suggesting this to obtain an even look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output is precisely what's expected, at least judging from the code.

You can remove the space by setting `\intextsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}

\begin{document}    

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}

\vspace{5mm}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the default value? Can we add or remove from it?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian It's a LaTeX parameter, so setting it might have adverse effects for other floats. Its default value is `12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix for this would be to use the `\vspace{-fontsize}` command to jump up by one line (change fontsize to the font size you are using).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}
\begin{document}    
\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace{5mm}
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{4cm}
    \vspace{-11pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\vspace{2mm}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following output that is visually correct:
[image]

Comment: Isn't this exactly the opposite of what the OP is asking?

Comment: @Rico  Ooops... You are right. At least the two figures now wrap similarly.